# commit change of Github downloaded as zip

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitkraken

I was working on a project with a friend, however instead of cloning the repo I downloaded it as zip and made several changes. In the mean time the remote one got update by my friend. Now, my code is outdated and I can't commit my changes as github don't recognize the diffences.
I tried cloning into a different location than copied the modified files into the cloned one however, this way I can commit my changes but with the outdated code( not the new changes made by my friend).
Any suggestion would be appreciated ?

Comment: Hi khalil. Could you include the output of error messages you are getting?
Also, could you detail in your queston whether or not the .zip contains the `.git` directory?

Answer (score 1):

A zip file is not a Git repository, and cannot be used as one.

A Git repository is, at its heart, really a big collection of *commits*.  **Each commit is like an entire zip file of source files.**  So a repository is, in effect, an ever-expanding set of *many* zip files.

What you *can* do, to deal with this "correctly"—which may be slightly to very painful, depending on what you did with the original zip file and/or your overall programming ability—is this, which starts with what you did try:

1. Keep the files you have now somewhere, out of the way.
2. Use `git clone` to make, for yourself, your own Git repository.  This clone will be filled with all the commits that are in the repository you're copying.
3. Somehow *find the original commit* from which you had Git make a zip file.  Create, for your own use, a new branch that selects *this commit*.

We'll come back to step 3 in a while, but first we should talk more about commits.  The brief one-sentence description above ("like a zip file") is not *wrong*, but doesn't capture the true essence of a commit.  (If you're impatient and already know all this, scroll to the end.)

#### What a Git commit is

Each Git commit is:

1. Numbered.  Every commit anyone ever makes, anywhere, gets a *unique* number.  To make this work, the numbers are *huge*, and seemingly random (although they're actually just outputs from a cryptographic hash function).  They're quite useless for humans, but the commit number is how Git *finds* a commit, so Git *needs* them.  Git calls these *hash IDs*, or more formally, *object IDs*.
2. Made up of essentially two parts.  The two parts of a commit are:

   - all the files, as if in a zip archive (but stored quite differently); and
   - some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: who made it, when, why (their log message), and so on.

Inside the metadata, Git keeps, for itself, one crucially important piece of information: each commit remembers the raw hash ID of some previous commit.  Actually, it's IDs, plural, of a set of commits, but *most* commits have just one in here.  Git calls that remembered hash ID the *parent* commit, and the commit itself is a *child* of that parent.

Because the hash IDs are cryptographic hashes of the complete contents of each commit, it's impossible to *change anything about any commit* after it's made.  And, because the hash IDs are unpredictable—they include such things as the *time at which the commit is made*—it's impossible to include the hash ID of a *future* commit in any commit we make.  So commits necessarily remember only their parents, never their children.

The result of all this is usually a simple, linear chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands in for the actual hash ID of our latest commit, whatever that is.  Commit `H` contains, in its metadata, the raw hash ID of earlier (parent) commit `G`, so we say that `H` *points to* `G`.  Meanwhile, `G` is also a commit, so it also has metadata, which contains the raw hash ID of *its* parent `F`: `G` points to `F`.  `F` in turn points backwards to some still-earlier commit, and so on.

This is the *history in a repository*, which is nothing more than the *commits* in the repository.  All (all?) we have to do is somehow find the *latest* one: `H` in the drawing above.  But note that history can *diverge:*

```
          I--J   [commits you might make starting from H]
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   [commits your friend makes, also starting with H]
```

Which of these commits is "the latest"?  The answer is really *both:* `J` is *your* latest, and `L` is *their* latest.

This is one form of *branching*.  Now, it's true that you'll be making your commits in *your* clone, and your friends will make their commits in *their* clones, but at some point, someone has to reconcile all these clones.  There are many tools for dealing with this but we won't even start on them here; this is really just to point out the many meanings of the word *branch*.  This word is badly over-used in Git, but to some extent, we're stuck with it.

#### A better overview of a Git repository

I already said that a repository as, at its heart, a collection—a database—of commits, and that's true, but again doesn't capture how we'll *use* this.  In fact, a repository is more like *several* databases, one of commits and other internal Git objects, *plus* one other big one and a lot of smaller ones as well.

Since humans are bad at remembering hash IDs, Git gives us an easy way out of this: it provides a *names* database.  These names include, but are not limited to, what Git calls *branch* names.  A name, in Git—a branch name, or a tag name, or the things Git calls *remote-tracking branch names* that I call *remote-tracking names* (since they're not actually *branch* names at all)—each name in Git serves the purpose of storing *one* hash ID.

That's all we need!  One hash ID suffices.  When the name *is* a *branch* name, that one hash ID is, by definition, the *latest* commit "on" that branch:

```
          I--J   <-- my-feature
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- bob-feature
```

Here, commit `H` is the *latest* commit *on `main`*.  It's not the latest commit ever: `I`, `J`, `K` and `L` are all later.  But it's the latest *on `main`*, and that's how a Git branch is defined.  Commit `J` is the latest *on `my-feature`*.

The actual set of commits "on" some branch is *all the commits we can find by starting at the end and working backwards*.  So commits up through `H` are on *all three branches*.  If you are used to other version control systems, this idea that commits are on many branches all at the same time may be downright weird.  But that's how Git works.

The other thing about branch names is that they *move*.  If commits `I-J` seem right, we can make them be *on* `main` now by moving the name `main` forward along the `I-J` line:

```
          I--J   <-- main, my-feature
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- bob-feature
```

Now all commits up through `J` are on the two branches, while commits `K-L` are only on `bob-feature`.  Or, if this was a mistake, we can force the name `main` to move back two steps to `H` again.

So this tells us how we use branch names in a Git repository: they help us—and Git—*find* commits, by finding whichever commit we want to claim is the *latest* for that branch.  The commits themselves do not, and cannot, move: they are all set in stone.  (We can change how we *draw* them: there's no reason we have to put `my-feature` on the top row, for instance, or we can draw vertically with newer commits higher up, or lower down, or whatever we like.  But the commits themselves are actually immutable.)

#### Your working tree and the index

If a commit holds a snapshot and is immutable—and it does and is—how are we to get any actual work done?  In fact, the files inside a commit are not only frozen for all time and compressed (as they would be in a zip archive), but are also *de-duplicated* across the entire repository contents, and are in a form that only Git itself can read.  So, just like any archive, we have to have Git *extract* the files *from* a commit before we can use them.

A normal repository therefore provides a work area—which Git calls a *working tree* or *work-tree*—where you can do your work.  When we *check out* a commit, Git fills in this working tree from the files saved in the snapshot.

Since most of what we do with Git involves making *new* commits—adding more history to the repository—you will now generally modify some of these files, and maybe create new files and/or remove existing files, and then you will want Git to make a new commit from the updated files.  In most version control systems, this is straightforward: you just run their "commit" verb.  **Git is not straightforward here.**

For various reasons, which you may someday agree with or not, Git now imposes upon you this thing that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  Why there are three names for this thing is a bit mysterious: I think it's because the original name *index* is poor, and the name *cache* is worse.  The name *staging area* at least reflects how you use it, most of the time.  But it isn't all that descriptive.  My own one-line description for Git's index is that **the index holds your proposed *next* commit**.

In other systems, when you use their commit verb, they look at your working tree to see what you've done.  Git, instead, looks at *its index*.  Whatever files are in Git's index, *those* are the files that go into the commit.  This means that the index effectively holds *copies* of the files that will go into the commit.

Git's internal format de-duplicates files.  This is pretty central to making Git efficient: without it, since every commit holds a full copy of every file, your repository would rapidly become obese.  But most commits mostly re-use the previous commits' files.  By storing just one copy, read-only and compressed—eventually super-compressed—Git keeps the storage requirements reasonable.

Meanwhile, what's *in* Git's index, aka the staging area, is *in this compressed and de-duplicated format*.  The difference between an index copy of a file and a committed copy is that you can have Git *replace* the index copy (deleting it, and putting in a different compressed-and-de-duplicated copy instead).  The commit can't be changed, but the index can.

So, when you first *check out* some commit, making it become the current commit, Git fills in your working tree—but also fills in *its index*, from that commit.  Now your proposed next commit *matches* the *current* commit.

As you modify working-tree copies—which Git *doesn't use*—they gradually become different from the index copies.  The index copies match the current, or `HEAD`, commit copies.  At some point though, you're ready to commit some file or files.  At this point you *must* run `git add` on the files.<sup>1</sup>

What `git add` does is simple, once you know about the index.  It:

- reads the working tree copy of the file;
- compresses it and checks for duplicates; and
- updates Git's index appropriately.

If the file *is* a duplicate, Git tosses out the compressed copy it just made and re-uses the old one instead.  If it's *not* a duplicate, Git arranges for the file to get stored forever once the commit gets made, and updates the index with that new internal object.  **Either way, the index copy now matches the working tree copy, except that the index copy is ready to be committed.**  Or, to put it another way: **`git add` updates your proposed next commit.**

---

<sup>1</sup>You can, if you like, use `git commit -a` as a shortcut.  If you're new to Git, this is tempting.  *Don't do it!*  It's a trap!  It lets you *avoid thinking about Git's index*, but eventually Git will slap you in the face with some surprising aspect of the index.  You need to have Git's index on your mind, even if it's just a sort of background presence.

Still, it's worth mentioning that what `git commit -a` does is, in effect, turn `git commit` into `git add -u && git commit`.  That is, first Git tries to update its index the way `git add -u` would.  Then, once that *succeeds*, commit goes on to its normal action.  There's a bunch of tricky stuff here though, having to do with pre-commit hooks and other issues.  It's better to avoid `git commit -a` as a beginner, and once you're an advanced Git user, you'll often *still* want to avoid `git commit -a` for other reasons.

---

#### `git status`, untracked files, and `.gitignore`

Before we actually simulate a `git commit` it's worth a brief look at the `git status` command and what Git calls *untracked files*.  Untracked files can be "ignored", which is kind of a misnomer.  *Tracked* files—the files that are not untracked—can't be ignored like this.

Because your working tree is *yours*, and because it's just an ordinary directory (or folder, if you like that term better) on your computer holding ordinary files, you can do anything you like here without Git knowing what you're doing.

That, plus the fact that you have to run `git add` on files before Git even bothers to *see* that you have done anything, makes working with Git painful.  To decrease the pain level, we have `git status`.  What `git status` does is simple to describe once you understand what `git diff` does.  (What `git diff` does is ... less simple if we were to cover all the details, but for now I'll just assume you know.)

What `git status` does, in part, is to run *two* `git diff --name-status` commands for you.  The first one compares `HEAD`—the current commit—vs Git's index.  It doesn't show the actual differences, but for any file that is *the same*, it says nothing at all, and for any file that is *different*, it says so.

This means that you can instantly tell what files you've *changed* in Git's index.  Those files are different in your *proposed next commit*.  If you do commit them now, they will be different in your new commit.

Files that *aren't* mentioned here must be *the same* in the current and proposed-next commits ... or, perhaps they're not in `HEAD` and Git's index at all.  Perhaps they are *all new* files.  If they *are* in Git's index, they will show up here as a "new file".  This section of `git status` output lists these as *files to be committed*, and each one is either new, modified, or deleted: it's new in the index, or both `HEAD` and index have the file and they're different, or it's in `HEAD` but *not* in the index.

Having gathered up that list for you, `git status` now goes on to run a second diff.  This time it compares the files that are in Git's index to the files that are in your working tree.  Once again, we can have:

- Files that are the same: they're in both, but match.  Git says nothing about these.
- Files that are different: they're in both both but *don't* match.  Git says these files are `not staged for commit`.
- Files that have gone missing from the working tree: they're in the index, but not visible to you.  The index contents are not directly observable, but you can view your working tree contents with any ordinary file listing and viewing command, because those are ordinary files.  This particular file isn't there any more, so Git says this file is deleted (but still `not staged for commit`).
- Files that are all new: they're not in the index, but *are* in your working tree.

This last group of files has a special status.  These are your *untracked files*.  **Any file that is in your working tree, but is not in Git's index *right now*, is an untracked file.**  The `git status` command separates out this last listing, of untracked files, from the first two:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   worktree.h

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Makefile
        deleted:    zlib.c

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        newfile.x
```

Here, I modified `worktree.h` and ran `git add` on it.  So the `HEAD` and index copies are *different*, and we see that in the `Changes to be committed` section.

I modified `Makefile` but *didn't* `git add` this, *removed* `zlib.c` and *didn't* `git add` the removal, and created an all new file `newfile.x` and *didn't* `git add` the file.  So in the section titled `Changes not staged for commit`, Git lists `Makefile` as `modified`, and `zlib.c` as `deleted`.  But it doesn't list `newfile.x` as added *here*.  Instead, that's down in the `Untracked files` section.

The untracked files here are separated out primarily for one reason: many things for which we *use* Git create a *lot* of untracked files.  We need a mechanism by which we can tell Git two things:

- don't *complain about* this file, and
- if I use an en-masse `git add .` or similar to just add *everything*, don't *add* this file either.

(We haven't really covered the en-masse "add everything" operations but they're very handy, once `git status` shows the right stuff.  We can add *everything*, or everything in some particular sub-directory, or whatever.  Git *won't* add any *untracked* file that we also told it to shut up about.)

That's a lot of detail to absorb, so let's stop here and move on to the next section.

#### Making a new commit from Git's index

Once you've arranged Git's index the way you want, so that `git status` *prints* what you want it to *print*—the files you intend to show up, do show up in the `to be committed` section, and they have what you want them to have in them and don't show up in the `not staged for commit` section—you can simply run:

```
git commit
```

Git will now collect from you all the *metadata* that needs to go into the new commit that it needs to get *from* you.  In particular, Git will:

- read your `user.name` and `user.email` settings to decide what to put into this part;
- use your computer's clock to figure out what time and day it is, for the time-and-date part;
- collect a *commit log message* from you, typically by opening up an editor on `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` (you can use `-m` to short-cut this); and
- use the *current commit*'s hash ID as the *parent* of the new commit.

Git will also turn all the files that are in the index into a new frozen-for-all-time snapshot to put in the new commit, and will then write all of this out *as* the new commit, which gets a new and unique hash ID.

Now, let's suppose that, at this point, we have this situation:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, my-feature (HEAD)
```

That is, we have two existing branch names, `main` and `my-feature`, that both *select commit `H`*.  We're *using* the name `my-feature`.  That means the *current commit* is commit `H`.  Git will have filled in our working tree and its index from whatever is in commit `H`.  Since then, we updated Git's index.

The `git commit` command has now taken the index contents, frozen them, added the necessary metadata, and written out a new commit, which got some new hash unique hash ID, but we'll just call it "commit `I`" here:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- my-feature (HEAD)
```

The *last step* of `git commit` is that it writes `I`'s actual hash ID, whatever that is, into the *current branch name*.  Since `HEAD` is attached to the name `my-feature`, that's the *branch name that gets updated*.  So now the name `my-feature` points to commit `I`.  By definition, our new commit `I` is now the *latest* commit on branch `my-feature`.

#### Your branch names are *yours;* remote-tracking names remember *theirs*

We now come to one other place where Git is a little weird, compared to many other version control systems.  On many systems, a branch name is a very solid thing, that lasts forever, and *everyone* who clones a repository uses the same branch names everywhere.  That's not the case in Git!  Instead, the *branch names* in a Git repository are *specific to that one repository*.

(They have to be, because of that trick where our new commit's hash ID just goes straight into the branch name.  We can only update *our* repository, not anyone else's, at this time.)

So, when you run `git clone` to copy some repository to your own laptop, or wherever the clone is going, **your Git copies all their commits, but none of their branch names**.  Instead of taking their branch names to make yours, your Git takes their branch names and *renames them*.  Technically they become something that's not a branch name at all: it's a *remote-tracking name* instead.

If you call the other Git `origin`—that's the standard name for "the other Git", when there's just the one other Git that you `git clone`-d from—your Git will take *their* `main` and turn it into your `origin/main`.  Your Git will take their `feature` and turn it into your `origin/feature`.  Your Git will turn their branches into your `origin/*` remote-tracking names.

(Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, as I mentioned before.  But they're not *branch* names at all.  They're just your Git's way of remembering *someone else's* branch names.  In that other repository, *they don't have `origin/` in front of them*.  That's why I just call them *remote-tracking names:* your Git is remembering some other repository's branch names, but not *as* branch names.)

Having copied all their commits, and turned all their branch names into remote-tracking names, your Git now has one problem: You have *no branch names*.  What name will your Git use to attach `HEAD` to?  There isn't any name!

The usual solution to this dilemma is that Git now creates *one* branch name in your repository.  Which one?  Well, that's what `git clone -b` is for: you tell your Git which name to create, based on one of their branch names.  If you don't use `-b`—and most people don't—your Git asks their Git what name they *recommend*.  That tends to be `master` or `main` (depending on who is hosting the Git repository you are cloning).  So they recommend their `main`, for instance, and your Git now makes your own `main` from your `origin/main`, which remembers their `main` (whew!):

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

Your Git now checks out this one branch name and all is normal: your *current branch name* is `main` and your *current commit* is whatever commit `main` selects.  (In this case I've drawn it as hash `H` as usual.)

If they have other branches, your Git repository might look more like this:

```
       I--J   <-- origin/feature1
      /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          K   <-- origin/feature2
```

Each of your remote-tracking names exists to find *their latest* commit, just as each of their *branch* names, in their repository, exists to find what is for them the latest commit.

Later, you can run `git fetch`.  When you do, your Git looks up theirs by name (`origin`: there's only the one other Git repository involved, so there's just the one standard name for it), calls up the URL listed under the name `origin`, and asks them what their branch names and latest commit hash IDs are.  If those latest commits match the remote-tracking names in *your* repository, there's nothing to do.  If not, your Git can get any *new* commits from them, using the hash IDs.  Now your repository has all of their commits, plus any of your own that you still haven't given to them.  Your Git now updates your remote-tracking names to remember their new latest commits.

#### We're finally ready to tackle your problem

Let's draw what you did:

- Get a zip file, downloading it to your laptop.  This is an archive made from some commit in their repository:

  ```
  ...--G--H   <-- main
  ```

  Your zip file thus *represents* commit `H`.  It's missing the metadata, but it has all the *files* from the snapshot.
- Extract the zip file.  You now have all the *files* from commit `H`, but no Git repository.
- Work on the files.
- Discover the mistake, and clone the repository itself to your laptop.

You now have a repository somewhere on your laptop, plus a folder full of files from commit `H`, but modified, somewhere else on your laptop.  The repository you have *now* might look more like this:

```
...--G--H--I--J--K   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

What you *want* to do, for cleanliness purposes, is *find which commit is commit `H`*.

You can run `git log`, which will spill out commits one by one.  If they have *branches and merges* this gets complicated, and you should read through [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452), but if not, you can maybe just search by date or something, to find commit `H`.  The actual hash IDs will be large, ugly, and random-looking, so they won't help any.  (To use them, you probably want to cut-and-paste with your mouse: it's really error-prone to try to type one in!)

There's a possible short-cut.  **If you still have the original zip file, look at its metadata.  There is a file comment holding the actual hash ID.  Grab it (with mouse or whatever) and you're golden!**  If not, how you find the right hash—the one I'm calling `H` here—is up to you.  Another trick you can use is this: `git diff` can compare *any* commit to *any file-tree*, even one that's outside the Git repository.  With `git log`, you get hash IDs; you can run:

```
git diff <hash> /path/to/unzipped/files
```

and get a diff listing.  If the *only changes you see* are *your changes*, the *`hash`* here is probably `H`.  You can use `git log`'s dates to get a short-list of candidates for this kind of `git diff`, and then use trial-and-error to find the closest commit.

Assuming you *have* found hash ID `H`, all you have to do now is *create a new branch name that points directly to this hash ID*.  To do that, use the `git branch` command:

```
git branch branch-xyzzy <hash>
```

(pick a better branch name, and use the mouse again for the cut-and-paste of hash IDs).  Now you have, in *your* repository:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch-xyzzy
         \
          I--J--K   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

You can now run `git checkout branch-xyzzy`:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch-xyzzy (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- main, origin/main
```

The files *in* your working tree are now those *from* commit `H`.  Copy the files in from the place you worked on the zip archive, use `git diff` and/or `git status` to figure out what to `git add` or just `git add .` and run `git status`, and you're ready to commit!  Your new commit will get a new, unique hash ID, and the name `branch-xyzzy` will point to it:

```
...--G--H--L   <-- branch-xyzzy (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- main, origin/main
```

or, equivalently:

```
...--G--H--I--J--K   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          L   <-- branch-xyzzy (HEAD)
```

Note how we can re-draw the drawing without actually changing any commits.  Get used to the fact that graph drawings morph a lot: whatever graph-drawing software *you* use, such as the stuff built in to GitKraken—you tagged your question with [gitkraken](/questions/tagged/gitkraken)—will have its own preferences.  They may or may not match up with yours.  The important things are the arrows from commits to earlier commits, and the various names that point to particular commits.  The arrows from commit to commit *can't* change, because no part of *any* commit can change, but the arrows from names *can*.

We make use of the last bit a lot.  For instance, now that you have:

```
...--G--H--I--J--K   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          L   <-- branch-xyzzy (HEAD)
```

you might want to use `git rebase`.  This *copies* commits, to new and improved ones.  Commit `L` might be fine, but it might be *better* if it built on commit `K`.  You can't actually do that, but you can make a *new and improved* commit—let's call it `L'`—that *does* do that:

```
                   L'  <-- improved-branch-xyzzy
                  /
...--G--H--I--J--K   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          L   <-- old-branch-xyzzy
```

If we now *delete* the old *name*, making commit `L` hard to find, and use the name over again to point to `L'` instead of `L`:

```
                   L'  <-- branch-xyzzy (HEAD)
                  /
...--G--H--I--J--K   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          L   ???
```

and then use any commit viewer to *look at the commits*, it will seem as though we changed commit `L`.  The new copy, `L'`, has a different *hash ID*, and points backwards to `K`, but makes the same *changes* that `H`-vs-`L` would show.  It has the same *commit message* that `L` had.  So if we don't remember the hash ID—and nobody ever does—we might not even know this happened!

Answer (score 0):

No need to overcomplicate. Any folder can be a git repo, as long as it has the .git folder. I did the following:

- clone the Github repo to another location
- copy the .git folder to your downloaded zip folder using the command line (`mv .git/ ~/new-location/.git/`)

Now create a new branch, commit everything, merge in main/master and fix all conflicts. Then commit again and you're done.